# Auto width of columns in html table

Tags: html-table, width

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </p>
</td>
<td>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  </p>
  <p> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </p>
  <p> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now it is obvious that the second column has more data and I want it to be wider than the first column (in this short example my wish may be strange, but imagine that paragraphs are much longer: in the first column I have a very long paragraph, while in the second column I have 3 paragraphs that are shorter than in the first column, but still rather long).

But it seems that the width of columns is calculated based on the longest paragraph. Since the first column contains the longest paragraph, in the browser the first column becomes wider than the second. Is it possible to force it to take all the three paragraphs into account when calculating the widths of the columns? [and thus make the second column wider than the first?]

Comment: You need to learn about CSS in order to do what you want.

Comment: Can you give me at least a hint - which CSS property would be relevant here?

Comment: I think that, as much as it sucks now, it will do you more good to learn how to research this on your own. I think a search for "how to control width with CSS" will give you a range of results to work with.